# i want to trigger a workflow when any field of a record is updated

Tags: workflow, custom-object, process-builder

This is a generic question. I have a custom object. I want workflow to trigger on the record when any of its field are updated.

That is:

> If record updated then evaluate workflow.

I am fairly new at Salesforce and want to know if this is achievable using standard Salesforce functionalities like workflow or process builder.

I have to use a time-dependent workflow so I am not being able to use created and everytime its edited

Comment: Did you try to check when LastModifiedDate is changed?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the standard process, but it takes two workflow rules instead of just one. First, create a custom checkbox on the object. Next, create a workflow rule that runs recursively, and checks the box immediately. Then, have a second rule that fires when the box is checked, and does not run recursively, and set your time dependent action there, along with a field update to uncheck the box. You should also be able to model this in the process builder. Please note that this design will not execute your delayed action more than once if there are multiple edits before it fires.

---

Example in Process Builder

N.B. I may not have this process perfectly correct, but by my understanding it should result in a delayed execution. The workflow rule method above I have used several times to do this very thing, so I know it works.

[image: Example in Process Builder]

Comment: @AlexanderAeonsTorn Rules are evaluated all at once, all updates are applied, and then if any rules force a reevaluation, all rules are evaluated again. We need to break the cycle with the unchecking, otherwise we have an infinite loop. People actually used this method as a poor man's scheduler system before we had the Schedulable interface in Apex Code.